Regular Expressions in Power Automate Desktop /Set Text Parsing

I'm working with a list extracted from OCR of receipt content in Power Automate Desktop and want to filter for specific numeric groups (prices). The issue is that numbers in 00-00 date format keep getting caught. I’ve tried the following:
1.Regular Expression: [+-]?\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+\b(.*?)
works for larger numbers but fails to capture smaller ones like -2.
2.Set Text Parsing Start Position:
This doesn't work; it always starts from the beginning.
For example, I tried setting a dynamically calculated starting position as a variable (in the case of the attached screenshot, 47), but it didn't work as expected.
Additional Information:
The target numeric group always appears at an index calculated as textVariable.length * 4 + 7
The date format is always 00-00, while the price may start with a + or -, may include thousands separators, and can contain decimal places.
I'd prefer to avoid For Each due to high processing time.
Any guidance is appreciated!

Updated answer: (?<!\S)([\d]|[+-])?\b(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)\b\s
Explanation:

(?<!\S) Ensures no non-whitespace character in the beginning

Regexr link: https://regexr.com/87i2a


Try this: ^([\d]|[+-])?(\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\b)\s (requires multiline)
Explanation:

^([\d]|[+-])? Optional start with 0-9, + or -
\s Having this at the end ensures the ending character is a whitespace, matching whole words


Regexr link: https://regexr.com/87i21


Thank you for your response! I tried it, but nothing was extracted. I'm not sure what the issue could be...

Could be the ^ expression requiring multi-line to function

I've updated my answer, do give it a try

Thank you for the continued support. I tested the regex, and it only extracts up to "85,251" in Power Automate. On regex testing sites, the expression seems to work fine, capturing all intended matches.

However, in Power Automate, which I understand is .NET-based, some values are consistently missing. I've tried adjusting the settings to mimic the .NET environment,

but some items are still being skipped.

Thank you for your assistance, kazcfz! I resolved the issue. It turns out that there was an action set to delete the extracted rows after the regex process, which caused the output to appear cropped. Your regex actually worked correctly. Thanks again for your help! Have a great day.

Hi there, [\d] is the same as \d. Note that in this construct (?<!\S)([\d]|[+-])?\b(\d{1,3} the digit [\d] will never have a match because it is followed by a word boundary and then an expected match for \d{1,3} Also in this part \b\s you can omit the word boundary as it is implicit between a digit and \s You could shorten it to (?<!\S)([+-])?(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?!\S) See https://regex101.com/r/qW1yBa/1
